# Calucate age from birth date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql with birth date column that saved as unix timestamp (bigint).

I want to write query like this:

```
SELECT ... as `age` FROM `tableName`
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE ... > 30
```

When the 3 dots is the function that calculate the age from the birth date.

I know about the function `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, but it's not good if I save the birth date as unix timestamp.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: It's not duplicate because we don't save the data in the same type. I'm using unix timestamp and he is using 2 columns...

Comment: You say you store it as a unix timestamp but that does not explain what you are doing... is it a string? a numeric? What exactly is going on... please give examples with actual data and expected results.

Comment: I said... I save it as big int..

Comment: This question shouldn't have been reffered to that answer. Not the same answer, not the same question. It was simply worong to do that, and it should be revoked. Also, the question itself was very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MySQL's [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html), we can combine `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, `NOW`, and `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

Supposing that `dob` is a Unix timestamp representing date of birth:

```
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, FROM_UNIXTIME(dob), NOW())
```

From there, it's simple enough to add a `WHERE` clause based on the column value.

[Live demo on SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08177/2)

Comment: What about negative timestamp? (people that born before 1/1/1970). It's giving me NULL for them..

EDIT: this is the solution: TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL dob SECOND), NOW())

Comment: Also please note that to use limit based on that column, I had to use HAVING:
SELECT * , TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, DATE_ADD( FROM_UNIXTIME( 0 ) , INTERVAL dob
SECOND ) , NOW( ) ) AS a
FROM `table`
HAVING a <18

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FLOOR((unix_timestamp() - birthday)/(86400*365)) AS age FROM table;
```

Comment: warning : this will fumble on leap years.

Comment: Won't it just be off by one day every four years? Person would have to be quite old before it would cause an error.

Comment: if you are satisfied with that margin of error, fine... but most people are over 4 years old and generally care about getting their birthday right.

Answer (score 0):

Use PERIOD_DIFF and let MySQL handle differences in leap years and other time stuff.  You said age, so I am assuming YEARS / MONTHS is good enough.

```
select period_diff(from_unixtime(1196440219, "%Y%m"), from_unixtime(1099440219, "%Y%m"))
```

returns back 36 months;

Simple exercise to convert to years :)

Could also use timestampdiff.  Need to do the same style parsing of the unix timestamp

```
select timestampdiff(YEAR, from_unixtime(1099440219, "%Y-%m-%d"), from_unixtime(1196440219, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: timestampdiff could also be used

Answer (score -1):

You can get the year and month of the timestamp with YEAR and MONTH functions respectively:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(birthdate),FLOOR((YEAR(CURDATE())*12+MONTH(CURDATE()) -(YEAR(from_unixtime(birthdate))*12+MONTH(from_unixtime(birthdate)))) / 12) as age FROM `table1`
```

and here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bf9b/5)

Comment: Don't work with negative Time Stamp (birthday prior do Epoch)